# Sublime Text CSS odd object syntax highlighting - plugin exists?

Tags: css, sass, sublimetext3

Just wondering if anybody knows about the plugin that could highlight every odd element in the stylesheet with slightly different background color? And I mean in the  editor itself, while we type - not in browser.

so say:

```
line 1 header { // <- black bg
Line 2 font-size: 1.5em; } // <- black bg
Line 3 } // <- black bg
Line 4 p { // <- dark gray bg
Line 5 font-size: 1.2em; // <- dark gray bg
Line 6 } // <- dark gray bg
```

etc

Comment: unfortunately, syntax highlighting themes are not programmable in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for any sublime text plugin, this would definitely be a page I would recommend. You can browse existing plugins here and install package control to further install more plugins.

Hope that helps.

https://sublime.wbond.net